# .mov file to .flv file conversion issue for ffmpeg using PHP

Tags: php, file-conversion

Is there any possible way to convert .mov file to .flv file conversion issue for ffmpeg using PHP. If yes, kindly let me know how to do?

Thanks in advance,

Fero

Comment: I think a simple google query would of been useful; [Using ffmpeg to convert mpg or mov to flv](http://www.johnrockefeller.net/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-mpg-or-mov-to-flv/)

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Kemo, though following the conventions of Stackoverflow, I'll offer the key bit provided by the link given:

```
ffmpeg -i <filename.mpg> -deinterlace -ar 44100 -r 25 -qmin 3 -qmax 6 <filename.flv>
```

I often transcode with ffmpeg and I don't ever bother to give all those flags, so you may find my typical use works well enough for you too:

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile.mov outputFile.flv
```

That's supposed to just change container formats and it tries to keep everything else as close as possible. I just did that and it seemed to work fine, though I'm uploading my flv somewhere it I'm having an issue, but that's probably totally unrelated to ffmpeg. Any tips?